# Como captar una variable de un while para borrar un dato en especifico

Tags: javascript, php

Hola buenas gracias primero que todo, soy nuevo en programación y realmente he buscado y buscado y no he conseguido información al respecto. esto es lo que pasa, necesito borrar un campo de la base de datos y que aparezca un confirm pero no puedo capturar el id que quiero para poder borrarlo.. ayuda porfa
aca el código:

```
    while (list($id,$nombre,$imagen)=mysql_fetch_array($query))
     { 
        echo "$nombre";
        echo "$imagen";
        echo "<a title='Presione aca si desea borrar' href='borrar.php?id=$id' onclick='preguntar();return false;'>eliminar</a>";
        echo "</br>";
     }
```

y este es mi código javascript

```
       <script language="Javascript">
   function preguntar()
     {  
      eliminar=confirm("¿Deseas eliminar este registro?");
      if (eliminar){
          //Redireccionamos si das a aceptar
       window.location.href = "borrar.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>";                                                                                           
       else
      alert('No se ha podido eliminar el registro...')
     }

      </script>
```

necesito es captar el id del registro 3 por ejemplo y guardarlo en una variable php y pasarla por url al window.location del js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías enviarle el id por parámetro a la función javascript

```
echo "<button onclick='preguntar($id)'>Eliminar</button>";
```

Y después en la función js:

```
<script language="Javascript">
   function preguntar(id)
     {  
      if (confirm("¿Deseas eliminar este registro?")){
          //Redireccionamos si das a aceptar
          window.location.href = "borrar.php?id=" + id;                                                                                           
      }else
          alert('No se ha podido eliminar el registro...')
     }

</script>
```

**Además no estabas cerrando correctamente el `if`**

Espero que te haya servido

Comment: Me borra directamente el registro, por que será??

Comment: No te redirige a la página?

Comment: Si me redirige, pero no me sale la ventana del confirm no comprendo el por que.

Comment: Ahí lo edité, trabajar con enlaces (tags "<a>") es una manera de rebuscársela si se necesita código de fondo que anule el re direccionamiento. Ahora queda mas sencillo, avisame si no funciona por favor

Comment: Fijate que corregí también lo del if

Comment: Muchisimas gracias ! ya me fijee el error que tenia en el if!